# What is the usage of std::multimap?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, multimap

I've just started learning STL containers, and I cannot understand why `std::multimap` exists. With `std::map`, we can access values by user-defined keys, but with `std::multimap` we cannot do that as the latter does not even have an overloaded `operator[]` and the same key can be mapped to several different values. To me, this looks like `std::multimap` is essentialy just something like `std::multiset<std::pair<K, V>>` with the `Compare` function operating on the `K` and we lose the main feature of a map which is the ability to access elements by key (as I see it). I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456882/use-cases-of-stdmultimap), but still couldn't comprehend the usecases given here. Could someone please give me several examples when we would use `std::multimap`?

Comment: hm, only now I read the quesiton you link. It seems to be an exact duplicate of your question. How is your question different from the one you link?

Comment: Note that if a question does not have the answer you are looking for then posting the same question again isnt the right way. It will be closed as duplicate, unless it is actually different from the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that `std::map::operator[]` is a little quirky. It is **not** the way to access elements in the map. Instead `std::map::operator[]` potentially inserts an element into the map and then returns a reference to either the element that was already present before or to the newly inserted. This may seem like splitting hairs, but the difference matters. The way to access a mapped_value given a key in a `std::map` is `std::map::find`. `std::multimap` has a `find` as well. No big difference with respect to that.

`std::map::at` has not counterpart in `std::multimap` because `std::map::at` returns a reference to the mapped_value for the given key, but in the multimap there can be more than one mapped_value for the same key, so it isnt obvious what a `std::multimap::at` should return if it existed. Finding and accessing elements can be done with `find` for both maps.

A `std::multimap<K,V>` can be compared to a `std::map<K,std::vector<V>>` but with the interface you'd expect when you want to map more than a single value to the same key. For example `std::multimap` iterators lets you iterate all key-value pairs in the multimap in one go. With the map of vectors you'd have to use the maps iterators and the vectors iterators. Using the map of vectors with standard algorithms is rather cumbersome.
Further, `std::multimap::count` returns the number of elements for a given key. With the map of vectors you would have to first find the vector for given key and call its `size`. This list is not complete, but I hope the difference gets clear.

One example for a multimap could be inhabitants of houses. In the same house lives more than one person. If you want to map street number to person you could use a multimap.

More generally, if you have a collection / container of elements and you want to divide them into distinct groups, you can use a multimap. A common use of `std::map` (or `std::unordered_map`) is to count frequencies, eg:

```
  std::map<int,int> freq;
  for (const auto& x : some_container) {
       ++freq[ x % 3 ];
  }
```

This counts how many elements of `some_container` are divisible by 3, without remainder, with remainder 1, or with remainder 2. If you want to know the elements rather than only count them you can use a `std::multimap`.

Comment: `std::map::at` returns a value corresponding to a given key and throws `out_of_range` if the key is not present

Comment: @Kaizakha and? `std::map::at` is a convenience for `std::map::find`. It is not a replacement for `std::map::operator[]`.

Comment: I just mean that accessing elements in `std::multimap` requires iteration (not under the hood, but explicitly by user). Even if we use `find`, [Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/find) says we can't know which element is to be returned and it also doesn't say anything about whether I can get the same element several times in a row which makes me questioning if I'm guaranteed to get all the occurences of a given key using `find`

Comment: @Kaiyakha use [`euqal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range) to get all elements for a given key

Comment: @Kaiyakha "std::multimap requires iteration " of course it does. If you do not want multiple values per key then you do not use a multimap